# Random int ids being generated for models in .net core 2.1 EF code first project

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I am starting a new project in .Net core 2.1 using entity framework - code first, and I'm seeing an issue with how ids are being generated for the models that I am creating - instead of incrementing by 1 for each new model created, it seems to be picking a new key at random.

I first created my model:

```
public class Geo
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Then ran Add-Migration to generate my migration script:

```
protected override void Up(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
    {
        migrationBuilder.CreateTable(
            name: "Geos",
            columns: table => new
            {
                Id = table.Column<int>(nullable: false)
                    .Annotation("SqlServer:ValueGenerationStrategy", SqlServerValueGenerationStrategy.IdentityColumn),
                Name = table.Column<string>(nullable: false)
            },
            constraints: table =>
            {
                table.PrimaryKey("PK_Geos", x => x.Id);
            });
    }

    protected override void Down(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
    {
        migrationBuilder.DropTable(
            name: "Geos");
    }
```

Then ran Database-Update to apply the migration. My controller endpoint to create a Geo looks like this:

```
[HttpPost]
    public async Task<IActionResult> PostGeo([FromBody] GeoDto geoDto)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return BadRequest(ModelState);
        }

        // Create the geo
        Geo geo = _mapper.Map<Geo>(geoDto);
        _context.Geos.Add(geo);
        await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

        return CreatedAtAction("GetGeo", new { id = geo.Id }, geo);
    }
```

Now I ran a post script to create several Geo objects, but instead of having incremental Ids, they just randomly - below is the list of Geo objects I see:

```
[
{
    "id": 1,
    "name": "NA"
},
{
    "id": 2,
    "name": "NA"
},
{
    "id": 1002,
    "name": "NA"
},
{
    "id": 1003,
    "name": "NA"
},
{
    "id": 2003,
    "name": "NA"
},
….
]
```

What could be causing this?

Comment: Have you tried decorating the `Id` property with the `[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]` and `[Key]` attributes?

Comment: SQL Server `IDENTITY` values are incremental but [may have gaps](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/106209/unexpected-gaps-in-identity-column).

Comment: Exactly same issue resolved https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/106220/23664

Comment: Thanks @DanGuzman - that's what I was looking for.